# Implementing a specific type of singly linked list

Tags: c++, insert, linked-list, queue, singly-linked-list

```
void insert(int number){
    Node* temp0 = NULL;
    Node* temp1 = head;
    Node* temp = new Node();
    int sum = 0;

    while(temp1!= NULL && sum<=number){
    // loop condition edited, before it was temp1!= NULL && sum>=number
        sum+=temp1->content;
        temp0=temp1;
        temp1=temp1->next;
    }

    if(temp0 == NULL){
        temp->content = number;
        temp->next = head;
        if(head!=NULL){
            head->content -= temp->content;
        }
        head = temp;
    }
    else{
        temp0->next = temp;
        temp->content = number - sum;
        temp1->content -= temp->content;
    temp->next = temp1;
    }// end of else
}// end of void insert
```

I ran into a problem, which i described in one of my previous questions, but still, i'm looking to implement the solution on my own.
In short, i want to make a "relative" list:
for example, for elements `1 5 7 2 4 6` the list would look like `1 1 2 1 1 1`

I would make a priority queue list `1 2 4 5 7 6`, and then i would change elements relative to the previous one:first element would stay 1,second would be 2-1 = 1, third would be 4-2 = 2, fourth 5-4 = 1 and so on.
When i form a priority queue, i would replace the current element with the difference of it's value and the value of the previous element.
I'm having problems implementing the insert feature. The code is given at the top of the question.

The idea is, i go through the list, adding the "difference" (which is the content field of my Node* structure) to a counter variable. When the sum counter becomes greater or equal to the element i need to insert, i found the position where to insert it.

If temp0 is null, i insert the element on the first position. If it's not the only element, i update the content of the next element - head, which was the previous first element.

If the number needs to be inserted somewhere in the middle of the list (or at the end), i update the content as sum - number, which would be a number >= 0, which is okay. Also, i update the content of the new's next element (`temp1`) as `temp->content - temp->content`.

For some reason, this does not work.
When i insert `4 2 8`, instead of `2 2 4`, i'm getting `4 -2 6` as the result list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your loop is "wrong", sum starts out being 0, so as long as `number` is not zero or negative, it never enters "find the place" loop. So every number is inserted at the beginning, rather than in its rightful place.

```
while(temp1!= NULL && sum>=number){
    sum+=temp1->content;
    temp0=temp1;
    temp1=temp1->next;
}
```

Change it to `sum <= number`, and I believe it will work. Not sure what you want to have happen if you insert the same number multiple times... May you want `sum < number` instead?

Edit: You will also have some method to detect that your "new" value is less than the existing one, and if so insert a new head, rather than after the existing number. I'm not sure what the exact code for this would be, but you do need to do something along the lines of:

```
 if (number < sum)
 {
     temp->next = head;
     head->content -= temp->content;
     head = temp;
 }
 else
 {
     ... existing insert code ... 
 }
```

Comment: If i enter the same number multime times i want to have several nodes with content == 0?

Thanks for pointing out the loop condition error.

So, i just need to change the loop to `while(temp1!= NULL && sum<=number)` ?

Comment: @Nicholas: Right, so using `sum <= number`, would insert the new number "last" in a list of equal numbers, where `sum < number` will insert the new item before the other ones of the same value. I think it doesn't actually make any difference, unless you are also storing something else along with the number (the number 4 is the same as 4, so it doesn't make any difference if we insert 4 before or after another 4 - but if you have some other data that isn't identical that goes along with the number, it may make a difference)

Comment: Hm, it doesn't work still. When i enter `4 2 8`, i get `4 -2 6`, as the result.

Since i'm making a priority queue, i can't have values less than 0, so what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Then edit your question with the new code and the new results (I take it the results changed?) Make sure you edit in the new code as an ADDITION to the existing code, not replacing it, or my answer so far will look strange.

Comment: Edited, i basically just changed that one thing in the while loop.

Comment: I just saw your updated answer, i'm not sure i quite follow.
What do you mean by "You will also have some method to detect that your "new" value is less than the existing one, and if so insert a new head, rather than after the existing number."?

The first if inserts a new head, in case temp0 == NULL, i insert a new head, and depending if the new element is the only one, i update it's content.

Or did i misunderstood what you meant to say?

Comment: So if your head is pointing at a value of `4` and you are inserting `2`, where do you insert it? It needs to become the NEW `head`, even if `temp0` is not NULL. I'm not 100% sure how you determine that, if `number < sum` is enough, or you need to check something else too (e.g. `temp0 == head`). But you definitely need to modify the head of the list if you insert a new element at the top of the list.

Comment: Okay, i understan you now, and i see that i have an error.
You suggestion that i check `if(number < sum)` condition doesn't seem to work correctly. I changed it to:
`if(head!=NULL && number<head->content)`, and now i got a more meaningful result, so most of my list works okay now, but i still get a few negative elements, so it's not quite finished?

Comment: I would suggest that you learn how to debug code then. I did the above analysis based on visual inspection of the code and a long-standing understanding of C and C++. But when it comes to understanding what is going on when you insert X into an existing list, there's nothing that beats stepping through the code. Alternatively, you can pretend to be the computer and step through your code on a piece of paper, and draw the list as you work out where things go, etc.

Comment: I think i figured out what the error is: the sum is not adjusted correctly if i have elements with content == 0.
In that case, the sum is not increased properly.

Comment: Nor should it increase, because you have two elements with the same value - so it should stay the same...